# How can one find a r-division of a graph with strongly sublinear separation profile (separable graphs)?

Tags: graph-algorithms, planar-graphs, shortest-path

Thanks for reading, let me provide the definitions first.

1. A separator of a graph $G$ is a set of vertices $C$ such that removing $C$ cuts the graph into two disconnected parts $A, B$ such that they are "roughly even size", namely, $|A|, |B|\le 2|G|/3$.
2. A graph has separation profile $f(n)$ if any subgraph of size $\le n$ has a separator of size $\le f(n)$.
3. A $(r, s)$ division of a graph is a division of a graph into *regions* and *boundaries* such that each region is of size at most r, and each region has at most s boundary vertices.

So my question is, how can one find a $(r, O(f(r)))$ division of a graph with separation profile $f(n)$? The strategy is, of course: repeatedly finding separators until you arrive at such a division. I know the work of Frederickson's: [Fast Algorithms for Shortest Paths in Planar Graphs, with Applications](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1405&context=cstech), see page 4-6, and another famous paper [Faster Shortest-Path Algorithms for Planar Graphs](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272574/1-s2.0-S0022000000X00384/1-s2.0-S0022000097914938/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEPv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDcs1v%2Fc7hJQMmjZ83Q0gJhnVllILPSth6zfmrhkKjUCwIgEdKerDu5zmUciwzaXwxyhbB5083ScyxPxTRRnrhK5LsqvAUIxP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDD4z6sWBrnnweNhw%2FCqQBSAEh0Hei%2FjRwY5IpCG%2BVsG4FGNCy9Qlf2rqYc3Yq6aF3t075GmW0x37APDZZK1DUiv49I4LeZbPAsjYkOQM59r7KOmt%2BRd65%2BXcVT8JFlyURTs%2BE0XepvtP4sndbwUVWfqudvLK%2BdqZ1PFSbG7nGucXPaVx%2BEShEXztzgyr4TytEQObCDhPICEx%2FfHBb%2FFCTW%2Bwi%2Be31spwc3nkvGqSXtMxFC9mfgrNuZSg8VrV6GkMEfv0MgHJRXkny3bAS7mnoVUzJNf4vIj6StsQEERU%2BUrOaP0689KraFeAaEcBd6SDk6bqz9dy9UWOZ7CKZ7dZlpITLLd4Kh9CjM%2BIcysUDIK%2BWSTFexSvgjc%2Fgwbdp7WgVZEjq7QH45%2FtaVZpFvyHQJ%2FNfuIjX5ffXRUlLzvgxqlzTI75XuKPjVyuE0gCHtHiL71p%2FTnArsD%2B2dFQ7Y0aMcw67a2ucz09bnoyalKLK1ZLulBULMqSMN%2FMNyBCmAAZNfVW10PpYCoks7eTE9ZCOoPaPYxTTwVpB2iblPge7hkGJpN3dqjBhE4Rln%2FnFYMWTZE4IINOfLUc5BqVmzV8H3DoG8i%2B7NVdHbwLQjIjovEAALOS8%2FdBpaCJIUfDpaSuQ2vxPanJP2JiLKXZS3792sDp6bycuCkDFR1wrZUahoI6wZaY91EVA6aEAGy0aminMaEADpYN%2FlD6DlrsjfDCLKyr3VKKDxbvX8cQ8Ib1IF7tKB%2F996g23w6ZX1Tay6kAQmBC7Rz%2BdIBeMa6W2OxLkuQu2rgkNHEPhyM2jI5P1WbzSkD4CFe9ZAFPTErpidhG8Wp5Vlz6craAxY4FMr7r33zoeW7FiaZBhLyhpweBVDy8JbxFhv1LRk1a%2BrcGRQGGMNaAiq4GOrEBq2umnpE2VvTJa4MK8Qq1NA%2Fw9Le2eE507B1EL6OGht6oXQ2Ekjp9bktL98%2F%2Bw%2FodUNiAzfupGrXdLa3IoYrJap%2BjxnqJmmpYPoYNxYlO%2BOGCBX2H1duNptTLDokfo5xDa5qSPm0ZUxfG5Qpy5I4Rzup16PWKTY2KgZGQBGBd%2BUSBMcPyAP0QVdzaqviYQBWZEJ5OyKgBzWC%2F1d5sN%2BXBlKdn9ap94MGF6bPh51b7gK0B&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240206T202059Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY3G4J3CNT%2F20240206%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=3f21b65c2518f5313703e8348bfd9ffb12300dbcf1b6a2f1e8f00efd0f87fd8a&hash=900ad417af34d8090d2295550936a313587390222a492e5a2aa90ab06593c7da&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022000097914938&tid=spdf-e9794733-676a-4ca9-a60c-d8827a2ee623&sid=7a83667a8fd0574ae4083db721da4734be1bgxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f155a5654515757050c00&rr=851618cbc9a90f3b&cc=us). In the second paper, before Lemma 2.1, they simply said: a simple adaptation of Frederickson's algorithm will suffice.

My confusion is exactly with this 'simple' adaptation. When you repeatedly find separators, you arrive at a bunch regions of size $\le r$. How can you continue to divide them into ones with small boundaries? In Frederickson's, this is done by using the famous [Planar Separator Theorem](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0136016?casa_token=zW586j3SvXkAAAAA:GGZ0Qx8prCXx61ajc2F75YZL0FeYXakHyVK00RauS9BsePX6phRtPnbenczd7HN_tTB-wRu-9qU), which says that given a subgraph, one could assign any weight to its vertices and we could find a separator which separates the weights. Using this theorem, we can assign weights to boundaries of a region, and assign no weights to the region itself, to find a small separator that cuts the boundary. Apply this repeatedly to regions with large boundaries, we are done. See page 6 of the first paper.

I don't yet see how to do this in graphs with separation profiles, precisely because I don't yet see how to cut regions with large boundaries into ones with small boundaries (in a way that the number of smaller regions is bounded). The r-division technique seems to be widely applied in graph algorithms, and I found some papers that will just state that there is a r-division in a separable graph without citation. I'm assuming I'm missing something simple here, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!